# Exact case insensitive match in spring-data mongo

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring data with mongo, and a repository. Eg:

```
@Query("{ 'userName' : ?0 }")
public User findByUsername(String username);
```

I want to make this case insensitive. I have used the following queries:

```
"{'userName' : { $regex : ?0, $options: 'i' } }"
```

This works, but it not only matches testUser, but also estUser.

I also tried

```
"{'userName' : { $regex : ^?0$, $options: 'i' } }"
```

But this cannot parse the query, because it tries to insert quotes in the regex.

```
com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
({ $regex : ^"testUser"$, $options: 'i' }
            ^
```

I get the same kind of problems if I try to use a /.../i regex.

Is there any solution for this, without having to use mongoTemplate, or constructing the regex myself?

Comment: You might want to consider that a case insensitive search in Mongo cannot be done efficiently. Ever document must be evaluated. It's common to store the data in the original format and whatever you consider more searchable, like converted to lowercase with all of the issues that crop up with Unicode chars.

Answer (score 27):

The easiest way probably is this:

```
interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, BigInteger> {

   List<User> findByUsernameIgnoreCase(String username);
}
```

Comment: Where is the implementation. Could you please explain how does this works ?

Comment: @KanagaveluSugumar actually there is no implementation. You can read about Spring Data Repositories and how the "magic" methods work.

Answer (score 20):

I just tried the following and it worked for me.

```
 @Query(value = "{'name': {$regex : '^?0$', $options: 'i'}}")
    List<Item> findItemsByNameRegexExactMatch(String name);
```

Answer (score 7):

**^ for the start, $ for the end**

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation( match(Criteria.where("fieldName").regex("^"+searchText+"$","i")) );
```

Answer (score 1):

use Text Search in mongo db ,please use version 2.6+